# XmlInclude or SoapInclude

Tags: web-services

I am developing a webservice that returns arrays of classes I define within the webservice. When I test it, I get: "System.InvalidOperationException: The type WebSite+HostHeader was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."

Here is part of the code:

```cs
[WebService(Namespace = "http://WebSiteInfo.Podiumcrm.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class WebSite : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public class WebSiteEntry
    {
        public string SiteName = "";
        public string Comment = "";
        public string IISPath = "";
        public int SiteID = 0;
        public ArrayList HostHeaders;

        public WebSiteEntry()
        {
        }
    }
    public class HostHeader
    {
        public string IPAddress = "";
        public int Port = 0;
        public string URL = "";

        public HostHeader()
        {
        }
    }


    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [TraceExtension(Filename = @"C:\DotNetLogs\WebSiteServices.log")]
    public WebSiteEntry[] WebSites()
    {...}
}
```

When I try:

```cs
[WebService(Namespace = "http://WebSiteInfo.Podiumcrm.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[XmlInclude(typeof(WebSiteEntry))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(WebSiteProperty))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(HostHeader))]

public class WebSite : System.Web.Services.WebService
{...}
```

I get: "The type or namespace name XmlInclude could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Points the the person who can give me the incantation that both compiles and executes!

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error you are receiving:

*The type or namespace name 'XmlInclude' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

It appears that you are missing the [System.Xml.Serialization Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.aspx). You can fully qualifying the XmlInclude type, like this:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(WebSiteProperty))
```

or add the namespace via the using directive:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization
```